# Why do we connect the same node to two different nodes at two different instances?

Tags: python, linked-list

I have found a solution to add the digits of two linked lists, l1 and l2 (where the digits have been reversed)

e.g.

```
Input: l1 = [2,4,3], l2 = [5,6,4]
Output: [7,0,8]
Explanation: 342 + 465 = 807
```

Here is the code:

```
class Solution:
    def addTwoNumbers(self, l1: ListNode, l2: ListNode) -> ListNode:
        head=l3=ListNode()      
        carry=0
        while l1 or l2:
            x = l1.val if l1 else 0
            y = l2.val if l2 else 0

            s=carry+x+y

            if s>9:
                carry = 1
            else:
                carry = 0

            s=s%10   

            l3.next=ListNode(s)    
            l3=l3.next

            if l2:
                l2=l2.next
            if l1:
                l1=l1.next

        if carry==1:
            l3.next=ListNode(1)

        return head.next
```

My question is simply related to the two `l3.next` lines (there are two). I can see for the first `l3.next = ListNode(s)` that we are simply connecting l3 with a new node ListNode(s)- which holds values s that is computed before.

However, I don't quite understand what l3.next = ListNode(1) does! Any ideas? I can kind of understand it- we are saying that `if carry==1` (i.e. the previous two digits' sum is >9) then we connect l3 to a new node with value 1?

Or does `l3.next = ListNode(1)` 'add 1 to the node after l3?'; this still wouldn't make sense to me, as `s=carry+x+y` takes into the account the carry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The line `l3.next=ListNode(1)` is only executed when there is still a carry *after the loop has finished*. It is not part of the loop.

Let's take this example:

```
 [5, 5, 5] +
 [5, 5, 5]
```

With this input, the loop will iterate three times, and after the loop, both `l1` and `l2` are `null`. In the first iteration we calculate 0 + 5 + 5. But that gives a carry. So the next iteration we calculate 1 + 5 + 5. And again we have a carry. The third (and last) iteration we again calculate 1 + 5 + 5. Again a carry. But as the loop does not iterate again, we have not done anything with that carry.

We need to add an extra node in the result to store this additional 1.

In other words, this code deals with the case where the number of digits in the result is *one more* than the input with the most digits has. This extra digit -- when present -- is always a 1. It cannot be a 2 or more. It's the same principle when you add multi-digit numbers with pen and paper.

Comment: Thanks Trincot, perfect explanation as usual.